# How can I include a "Select All" option in my combo box?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a combo box that has the list of my distributors, when I select a distributor in the combo box I have a sub-form that list the transactions of that specific distributor.

Now I want to include a `"Select All"` option in the combo box that will display all the transactions of my distributors. I tried to do it through the `UNION` Query and so far it hasn't worked.

Here is the code below:

```
SELECT Sous_Compte.Sous_Compte_ID, Sous_Compte.Numero_Sous_Master, Sous_Compte.Prenom & " " & Sous_Compte.Nom AS Nom 
FROM Sous_Compte

UNION SELECT "*" AS Sous_Compte_ID, "(All)" as Numero_Sous_Master, " " AS Nom from Sous_Compte

ORDER BY Sous_Compte.Numero_Sous_Master;
```

And this the error message I get whenever I select `"(All)"`:

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be
>   evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many
>   complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning
>   parts of the expression to variables.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193222/discussion-on-question-by-douk-how-can-i-include-a-select-all-option-in-my-com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Master/Child Links properties won't work because * character can't be a key value. But can reference combobox in a dynamic parameterized query, such as:

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID LIKE Forms!formname!comboboxname;`

Then that query can be RecordSource of a form.

After selecting item from combobox, must refresh/requery form. Can use combobox AfterUpdate event or a button Click event. If using a single form then simply: `Me.Requery`. If using a subform, must reference through the subform container control: `Me.subformcontainername.Requery`. (Note this is correcting my comment that subform would fail when opening - a subform will work.)

This dynamic parameterized query can also be the RecordSource of a report. Or if you don't want this same query as report RecordSource, can use WHERE CONDITION argument of OpenReport method:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "reportname", , , "ID LIKE Forms!formname!comboboxname"`

Comment: Thanks @June7 it worked for me. I really appreciate your help. I will Use docmd solution for the report later on and let you know.

Comment: the docmd.openReport solution works perfectly. Thanks again, God Bless you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I added the form you helped me with (let's call it Form A) to a Navigation Form and it is not working properly on the Navigation Form. The problem occurs whenever I change the value of the combo box or whenever I move to the TAB that has Form A on my Navigation Form. It ask to "Enter Parameter value", my guess is that the reference to the combo box on Form A not longer works on the Navigation Form. How can I make the combo box work on the Navigation Form?

Comment: I wish there was another way to contact you, so I wouldn't bring up more questions to this post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never use Navigation Form but tested. The query works fine. VBA `Me.NavigationSubform.Requery` works. Start a new question if you still have issues.

Comment: in what event did you put Me.NavigationSubform.Requery?

Comment: Combobox AfterUpdate. Same options as with normal form.

Comment: Again, works for me. Can't replicate error, can't advise solution.

Comment: When I put the code in the AfterUpdate of the combo box mine gave the following error: "Compiler Error: Method or data member not found".

Comment: Then you need to edit this question or start a new question and give details - SQL statement and code and names of objects. It all works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The fields of the two queries must match:

```
SELECT 
    Sous_Compte.Sous_Compte_ID, Sous_Compte.Numero_Sous_Master, Sous_Compte.Prenom & " " & Sous_Compte.Nom AS Nom 
FROM 
    Sous_Compte
UNION 
SELECT 
    0, "(All)", ""
FROM
    Sous_Compte
ORDER BY 
    Sous_Compte.Numero_Sous_Master;
```

Comment: The fields of the two queries are matched. Take a look again.  The problem reside somewhere else.

Comment: Look again. No star (that selects all fields).

Comment: The asterisk is within quote marks so it is seen as text, not special character. Query with asterisk tested and works. Has a record with asterisk and field is treated as text, not number.

Comment: @June7: You are right. Thanks. However, returning a text star for an unknown ID makes little sense.

Comment: I think OP wants the * to cause all records to return. It does work with parameterized query. Criteria `LIKE Forms!formname!comboboxname` under ID field in query will see the * from combobox as wildcard and all records return. Selecting another value returns only matching records. So this answer does not resolve question.